# Why does dim=1 return row indices in torch.argmax?

Tags: python, matrix, pytorch, tensor, argmax

I am working on `argmax` function of PyTorch which is defined as:

```
torch.argmax(input, dim=None, keepdim=False)
```

Consider an example

```
a = torch.randn(4, 4)
print(a)
print(torch.argmax(a, dim=1))
```

Here when I use dim=1 instead of searching column vectors, the function searches for row vectors as shown below.

```
print(a) :   
tensor([[-1.7739,  0.8073,  0.0472, -0.4084],  
        [ 0.6378,  0.6575, -1.2970, -0.0625],  
        [ 1.7970, -1.3463,  0.9011, -0.8704],  
        [ 1.5639,  0.7123,  0.0385,  1.8410]])  

print(torch.argmax(a, dim=1))  
tensor([1, 1, 0, 3])
```

As far as my assumption goes dim = 0 represents rows and dim =1 represent columns.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It's time to *correctly understand* how the `axis` or `dim` argument work in PyTorch:

[image: tensor dimension]

---

The following example should make sense once you comprehend the above picture:

> ```
>     |
>     v
>   dim-0  ---> -----> dim-1 ------> -----> --------> dim-1
>     |   [[-1.7739,  0.8073,  0.0472, -0.4084],
>     v    [ 0.6378,  0.6575, -1.2970, -0.0625],
>     |    [ 1.7970, -1.3463,  0.9011, -0.8704],
>     v    [ 1.5639,  0.7123,  0.0385,  1.8410]]
>     |
>     v
> ```

```
# argmax (indices where max values are present) along dimension-1
In [215]: torch.argmax(a, dim=1)
Out[215]: tensor([1, 1, 0, 3])
```

---

**Note**: `dim` (short for *'dimension'*) is the torch equivalent of *'axis'* in NumPy.

Comment: Thanks a lot, So basically what i understand is we should consider the shape of the array to identify the axes

Answer (score 3):

Dimensions are defined as shown in the above excellent answer. I have highlighted the way I understand dimensions in Torch and Numpy (dim and axis respectively) and hope that this will be helpful to others.

Notice that only **the specified dimension’s index varies during the argmax operation**, and the specified dimension’s index range reduces to a single index once the operation is completed. Let tensor A have M rows and N columns and consider the sum operation for simplicity. The shape of A is (M, N). If dim=0 is specified, then the vectors `A[0,:]`, `A[1,:]`, ..., `A[M-1,:]` are summed elementwise and the result is another tensor with 1 row and N columns.  Notice that only the 0th dimension’s indices vary from 0 throughout M-1. Similarly, If dim=1 is specified, then the vectors `A[:,0]`, `A[:,1]`, ..., `A[:,N-1]` are summed elementwise and the result is another tensor with M rows and 1 column.

An example is given below:

```
>>> A = torch.tensor([[1,2,3], [4,5,6]])
>>> A
tensor([[1, 2, 3],
        [4, 5, 6]])
>>> S0 = torch.sum(A, dim = 0)
>>> S0
tensor([5, 7, 9])
>>> S1 = torch.sum(A, dim = 1)
>>> S1
tensor([ 6, 15])
```

In the above sample code, the first sum operation specifies dim=0, therefore `A[0,:]` and `A[1,:]`, which are `[1,2,3]` and `[4,5,6]`, are summed and resulted in `[5, 7, 9]`.  When dim=1 was specified, the vectors `A[:,0]`, `A[:,1]`, and `A[:2]`, which are the vectors `[1, 4]`, `[2, 5]`, and `[3, 6]`, are elementwise added to find `[6, 15]`.

Note also that **the specified dimension collapses**. Again let A have the shape `(M, N)`. If dim=0, then the result will have the shape `(1, N)`, where dimension 0 is reduced from M to 1.  Similarly if dim=1, then the result would have the shape `(M, 1)`, where N is reduced to 1.  Note also that shapes (1, N) and (M,1) are represented by a single-dimensional tensor with N and M elements respectively.

Answer (score 1):

```
    |
    v
  dim-0  ---> -----> dim-1 ------> -----> --------> dim-1
    |   [[-1.7739,  0.8073,  0.0472, -0.4084],
    v    [ 0.6378,  0.6575, -1.2970, -0.0625],
    |    [ 1.7970, -1.3463,  0.9011, -0.8704],
    v    [ 1.5639,  0.7123,  0.0385,  1.8410]]
    |
    v
# argmax (indices where max values are present) along dimension-1
In [215]: torch.argmax(a, dim=1)
Out[215]: tensor([1, 1, 0, 3])
```

Taking this one step further,for those who come in later:
this devolves into 4 different comparisons:when `DIM is 1`

```
Comparison for ind=0: argmax([-1.7739,  0.8073,  0.0472, -0.4084]) = 1
Comparison for ind=1: argmax([ 0.6378,  0.6575, -1.2970, -0.0625]) = 1
Comparison for ind=2: argmax([ 1.7970, -1.3463,  0.9011, -0.8704]) = 0
Comparison for ind=3: argmax([ 1.5639,  0.7123,  0.0385,  1.8410]) = 3
```

This therefore answers for each row, get me what column has the max value

When `Dim is 0`:

```
Comparison for ind=0: argmax([-1.7739,0.6378,1.7970,1.5639]) = 2
Comparison for ind=1: argmax([0.8073,0.6575,-1.3463,0.7123]) = 0
Comparison for ind=2: argmax([0.0472,-1.2970,0.9011,0.0385]) = 2
Comparison for ind=3: argmax([-0.4084,-0.0625,-0.8704,1.8410]) = 3
```

Which answers the question for each column, get me what row has the maximum value

When you get multi-dimensional (i.e > 2 dims/axis) it will look across all remaining dimensions to find largest one.